# how to make a simple application to run on blackberry storm (touch screen mobiles)?

Tags: blackberry-storm

Hello i am newbie in blackberry app. development.I need my **applications to run on Blackberry storm as well(i.e. touch screen mobiles).**. Is there any way to do that. Kindly help. Again tell me the **latest blackberry JDE versions or eclipse plug ins that works with touch events**.
Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum version that you need for touch events is 4.7.

The latest eclipse and JDE versions are available on RIMs [developer homepage](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/).

[Here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/13222/CS_Adding_simple_touch_event_handling_to_app_705068_11.jsp) is a link (PDF in the link) to a code sample for adding a touch event to your application.